# What browser can update the webpage live as I edit HTML in the inspector?

Tags: browser, frontend, firebug, web-inspector

I used to use Firefox and the beloved plugin Firebug to work with web pages, since you can edit the HTML-code, and see the result on the page as you edit it.

The last version to support this and firebug was Firefox 49, and all newer Firefox, Chrome and Safari version doesn't have this. You can edit the code, but you have to click outside or CMD/CTRL-Enter to confirm the changes.

Why isn't this implemented in newer browsers, it doesn't seem that complicated, and it's so useful. I can't believe I can't find anyone else discussing this on the Internet.

Is there any browser version and/or plugin to Chrome that can do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, no browser allows this and there isn't any extension for that, unfortunately.

Though there is a [feature request for the Firefox DevTools asking to add live editing](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1067318).